# How to centre this video pop-up

Tags: popup

thank you for taking some time to reply.

I need help to create a video pop-up with a Title and a description. The user should be able to open the pop-up both by clicking the image and the title. We tried several codes for our website, but when we make the images clickable, it disrupts the whole layout. We are not coding experts, so we don't know the issue because the code worked fine outside Squarespace. Therefore, we were hoping someone could help us create a simple video pop-up with a clickable image and title.

I know it is a lot to ask; thank you for your time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need a video pop up to create a Testimonials page. To open the pop-up the customer should click both on the title and on the image of the testimonial. (The pop-up content needs to have a title, a video and a description.) This code should be replicable for 20 testimonials, as soon as possible... Our team tried to work on finding and composing a code that would work with Squarespace, but failed; this is why we are asking here for help. I hope this clarifies the latter question.